# Create Excel file with data from a stored procedure to attach it into an email in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I need to create an Excel file with data from a stored procedure and then attach that file to an email in Power Automate.

I already have the process to do everything, first the extract of data from the stored procedure, and I used to add it into the body's email, but now I have to paste it into an Excel (I imagine that it should be saved in OneDrive) but I am not sure how to do the file and attach it to the email.

Answer (score 0):

i might not fully understand, but you could use 2 flows. 1 flow could be triggered by an email being received (i've used SSRS to send query results to myself). This same flow uses this email to create a one drive file. The second flow is triggered when a one drive file is created. I then create an excel online table with that and end up emailing it as an attachment.